# write_gif is automatically changing the resolution of the resultant gif as compared to the supplied video(mp4) file? How to avoid that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, gif, moviepy

Please see the code below and the result. How can we get the gif in the original dimensions. The moviepy documentation doesn't seem to say much.

`from moviepy.editor import *  import os  os.chdir(r'G:\')  clip = VideoFileClip("VID.mp4").subclip(6*60, 6.1*60) clip.write_gif("vidgif.gif",program = 'ffmpeg')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue here -

https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/586

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers may become invalid if the linked page changes.